# jquery change element position in dom

Tags: jquery, html

Hey i wanna change position of some element in DOM, for example .off-date in .teach2 but if these elements are twice or more on page it prepands two or more elements instead just one, so the result is that i got four .off-date elements on page instead just two .. Can i prevent this somehow ? Any advice welcomed..

```
if ($(window).width() < 767) {

        $(".teach2 .off-place").prependTo($(".teach2 .off-date"));

     }


       <div class="teacher-box teach2">

            <span class="typo off-name">Magdalene</span>
            <span class="typo off-type">with partners</span>
            <span class="typo off-date">wed DEC 15 </span>
            <span class="typo off-time">19.30 - 20.30</span> 
            <span class="typo off-place">at home</span>

        </div>

        <div class="teacher-box teach2">

            <span class="typo off-name">Magdalene</span>
            <span class="typo off-type">with partners</span>
            <span class="typo off-date">wed DEC 15 </span>
            <span class="typo off-time">19.30 - 20.30</span>
            <span class="typo off-place">at home</span> 

        </div>
```

Comment: Mind creating a JSFiddle with the problem?

Comment: can you clearly explain where do you want to place off-date to, you have mentioned to change off-date but in code you have written as off-place,off-place is not there in the markup

Comment: sorry its update now ... I need place .off-place before for example .off-date .. it works but the problem is that it duplicate in one teacher-box two .off-place elements

Comment: Are you sure `prependTo()` is really what you want? That will put one span inside the other span. Maybe you really want `insertBefore()` so that they'll stay at the same level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.each()` to iterate over each `.off-place`, so you can prepend it to the `.off-date` in the same DIV.

```js
$("#but").click(function() {
  $(".teach2 .off-place").each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo($(this).siblings(".off-date"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="but">Click to move</button>
<div class="teacher-box teach2">

  <span class="typo off-name">Magdalene</span>
  <span class="typo off-type">with partners</span>
  <span class="typo off-date">wed DEC 15 </span>
  <span class="typo off-time">19.30 - 20.30</span> 
  <span class="typo off-place">at home</span>

</div>

<div class="teacher-box teach2">

  <span class="typo off-name">Magdalene</span>
  <span class="typo off-type">with partners</span>
  <span class="typo off-date">wed DEC 15 </span>
  <span class="typo off-time">19.30 - 20.30</span>
  <span class="typo off-place">at home</span> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do to achieve in pure css.

```css
.teacher-box {
  display: flex;
}
.typo {
  margin: 0 1px;
}
.off-name {
  order: 1;
}
.off-type {
  order: 2;
}
.off-date {
  order: 3;
}
.off-time {
  order: 4;
}
.off-place {
  order: 5;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .off-name {
    order: 1;
  }
  .off-type {
    order: 2;
  }
  .off-date {
    order: 4;
  }
  .off-time {
    order: 5;
  }
  .off-place {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="teacher-box teach2">

  <div class="typo off-name">Magdalene</div>
  <div class="typo off-type">with partners</div>
  <div class="typo off-date">wed DEC 15 </div>
  <div class="typo off-time">19.30 - 20.30</div>
  <div class="typo off-place">at home</div>
  
</div>
```

Assuming that you are trying to change the position of the content on window resize at 768px.

You could make the teachebox as a flex layout and write a media query to change at 768px;

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which element to alter. XPath or CSS selectors can help with that.

On a side note, it looks like you're trying to create an adaptive webpage. Maybe you should look into another approach? Flexible layouts, responsive design - it's already been invented.

Comment: Yes but even with flexbox i cant do advance moves in dom

Comment: Then try XPath or CSS selectors, or use div IDs.

Comment: @AlexS ? can you shed some light on "XPath" or "div IDs" ?

Comment: In most cases you can assign almost any element an id: <div id="myDiv">. This allows you to select this exact element for any purpose. With JQuery it will be: $("#myDiv"). Note that IDs must be unique on the page.

Comment: As for XPath, it's a way to navigate through XML documents. You can read more about it here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/ But I seriously doubt that it's relevant in your case.

Comment: And here's for CSS selectors: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ - if there's no other way, you can try selecting first or last element within certain class.